# Split String based on Uppercase and Numbers

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to split a `String` when an uppercase letter or a number is found.

Ive got it working for Uppercase letters already with answers on other questions here:

```
String s = "HeFNeO2H3Be1H";
String[] r = s.split("(?=\\p{Upper})");
    for (int i = 0; i<r.length; i++){
        System.out.println(""+r[i]);
```

How can I add numbers to the `regex` so the String s will be split at uppercase letters AND numbers. Thx for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String s = "HeFNeO2H3Be1H";
  String[] r = s.split("(?=[A-Z0-9])");
    for (int i = 0; i<r.length; i++){
        System.out.println(""+r[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same here, result is ` eee  `-

Answer (score 1):

Use the simplest pattern:

```
[A-Z0-9]
```

Comment: This results in the output: `
e

e




e
` (so basically the e's from He, Ne & Be)